# My application is crashing when i'm getting push notification

Tags: android

I am updating my fragment from sqlite when getting push notification from server when i was on same fragment it's update. But when i was on another activity and getting push notification my application is crashing.

Here is my exception :

```
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631): Process: com.newt.vdsi.driver, PID: 17631
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1360)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1378)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at com.newt.vdsi.driver.Home$1.onReceive(Home.java:517)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-28 22:18:03.302: E/AndroidRuntime(17631):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the updates should go to a Service, and then the Activity/Fragment's `onCreate()` should pull from the Service for data?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the host activity for that fragment has performed onStop() and a commit() is called on a FragmentTransaction after that has happened(that is your when commit is called and your host activity is hidden).

Try using a local broadcast with a custom intent filter when push notification is received and use a broadcast receiver in your fragment for the update logic.

In which case if the fragment is visible when push notification happens it'll update otherwise let its onCreateView() handle the logic.